# Navigation Controller back button not showing when using a second storyboard

Tags: ios, xcode, storyboard, navigationcontroller

I have 2 storyboards.
in Main.storyboard I have a view controller with a button. When the button is clicked I load the second storyboard Second.storyboard. This is the code I use to load the Second.storyboard

```
DispatchQueue.main.async {
    let storyBoard : UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Second", bundle:nil)

    let nextViewController = storyBoard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "Tools") as UIViewController
    self.present(nextViewController, animated:true, completion:nil)
}
```

In Second.storyboard I have a navigation controller and 2 view controller A and B.

The problem is that when running, I don’t see the back button in B to go back to A.

Things that I have tried:
I have created another project. I embedded a navigation controller and 2 view controllers A and B in main.storyboard. This works fine. The back button is shown. This tell me that I am missing something when I load the second storyboard

I have tried adding this

```
// Do any additional setup after loading the view.
self.title = "Title"

let navigationBar = navigationController!.navigationBar
navigationBar.tintColor = UIColor.blue

let leftButton =  UIBarButtonItem(title: "Left Button", style: UIBarButtonItemStyle.plain, target: self, action: nil)
let rightButton = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Right Button", style: UIBarButtonItemStyle.plain, target: self, action: nil)

navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = leftButton
navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = rightButton
```

I see some samples that load storyboards without this line `DispatchQueue.main.async {}`. However; If I don use it I get an error and the program crush.

How do I add the Navigation Controller? I select the first View Controller, Editor, Embed in, Navigation Controller.

I am trying to display a navigation controller on a second storyboard and it is not showing the back button.

Needles to say that This is the second App I am trying to do and any help would be very much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

What are you seeing after presenting "Second"? Are you seeing a nav header/title area at all? Just the Back button is missing from it?

- How are you pushing B from A?
- I suspect "Tools" is not the Navigation Controller in "Second". When calling `storyBoard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "Tools")` you want to be referencing the Nav Controller - not A.

Comment: Graham Perks, Thanks for the piece of code. Unfortunately; it doesn't load the  next view controller. No errors. It just doesn't load the next View.

Comment: Ah, sorry, I misunderstood. I've changed my answer.

Comment: This is how I load the second Storyboard. DispatchQueue.main.async {
    let storyBoard : UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Second", bundle:nil)

    let nextViewController = storyBoard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "Tools") as UIViewController
    self.present(nextViewController, animated:true, completion:nil)
}. I dont see any title, I don see the back button.

Answer (score 0):

Calling presentViewController presents the view controller modally, outside the existing navigation stack; it is not contained by your UINavigationController or any other. If you want your new view controller to have a navigation bar, you have two main options:

Push the new view controller onto your existing navigation stack, rather than presenting it modally:

let VC1 = self.storyboard!.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("MyViewController") as! ViewController
self.navigationController!.pushViewController(VC1, animated: true)

I found this answer in this posthttp://stackoverflow.com/questions/25444213/presenting-viewcontroller-with-navigationviewcontroller-swift