# Can't get reference to an UIViewcontroller

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller

I have this:

```
guard let mapVC = mapSB.instantiateInitialViewController() else { return }

mapVC.navigationItem.title = "Some title string"
//        (mapVC as! MapViewController).string = "Some string"
//        (mapVC.navigationController?.viewControllers.first as! MapViewController).string = "Some string"
```

I have tried both of the commented out lines, but it crashes on whichever line I comment back in. And here is the po of mapVC:

```
po mapVC
error: <EXPR>:3:1: error: use of unresolved identifier 'mapVC'
mapVC
^~~~~~~~~
```

Which is weird, because it does correctly set the mapVC.navigationItem.title as "Some title string."

If this helps, mapVC is embedded in a navigation controller in mapSB.

Edit:

The crash message is:

```
Thread 1: EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION (code=EXC_I386_INVOP, subcode=0x0)
```

And mapVC is of type MapViewController, hence the casting.

Comment: What is the class of the initial view controller in your storyboard?

Comment: What is the crash message?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of embedding that view controller in a navigation controller within that storyboard (which is probably not being picked up because you are expecting your `instantiateViewController` to return a MapViewController), try creating the navigation controller *programatically*, like this:

```
guard let mapVC = mapSB.instantiateInitialViewController() as? MapViewController else { fatalError("couldn't load MapViewController") }
mapVC.navigationItem.title = "Some title string"

// assuming mapVC has a .string property
mapVC.string = "Some string"

let navController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: mapVC) // Creating a navigation controller with mapVC at the root of the navigation stack.
self.presentViewController(navController, animated:true, completion: nil)
```

more information can be seen [in this related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25444213/presenting-viewcontroller-with-navigationviewcontroller-swift).

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead.

```
    guard let navigationVC = mapSB.instantiateInitialViewController() as? UINavigationController,
        let mapVC = navigationVC.viewControllers.first as? MapViewController else {
            return
    }

    mapVC.navigationItem.title = "Some title string"
    mapVC.string = "Some string"
```

If your initial `MapViewController` is embedded in an `UINavigationController`, then `mapSB.instantiateInitialViewController()` is going to return the embedding `UINavigationController` instance. So you'll need to call `navigationVC.viewControllers.first` to get at your `MapViewController` instance.

In your initial code, the line

```
    (mapVC as! MapViewController).string = "Some string"
```

failed because `mapVC` wasn't an instance of `MapViewController`, so using `as! MapViewController` caused a crash.

The `as!` operator was also causing the crash in this line

```
    (mapVC.navigationController?.viewControllers.first as! MapViewController).string = "Some string"
```

Since `mapVC` is the root navigation controller, `mapVC.navigationController` evaluates to `nil`. Therefore `mapVC.navigationController?.viewControllers.first` resolves to `nil`, and trying to force conversion of `nil` with `as! MapViewController` results in a crash.