# Present ViewController modally with navigation Bar not changing the stackView

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar

I am trying to present a view controller modally and I want it to have a navigation bar.

I found a similar question here [presenting ViewController with NavigationViewController swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25444213/presenting-viewcontroller-with-navigationviewcontroller-swift)

I do not want to change the RootViewController. I want either to add the navigationBar in the VC or to present modally already with one.

Thanks

Comment: What's your question again?

Comment: @glenn keep the current stackview - present modally a VC with a navigation bar or present modally a VC + add a navigation bar

Comment: Can you share some codes? Screenshot of the problem? I still don't get that "keep the current stackview"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can always create a `UINavigationController` instance and add your view controller (the one you want to present modally) to it. Then, modally present the new `UINavigationController` instance instead of your view controller. This will show your view controller (because it is contained in the `UINavigationController`) with a navigation bar (because it is in a `UINavigationController`).

Here is an example:

```
let rootViewController = UITabBarController() // Lets assume this is your root view controller
let modalViewController = UIViewController() // Lets assume this is the view controller you want to present modally

// Here we wrap the modal controller in a navigation controller and then present it modally
let navigationController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: modalViewController)
rootViewController.present(navigationController, animated: true, completion: nil)
```